# Create new code refactoring for ReSharper

Tags: resharper

Is it possible to create a code refactoring for ReSharper like the one that checks a parameter for null.

[image]

This will generate the following guard check if we apply that to the method below

```
public void Method(string value)
{
     if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
}
```

Is it possible to create a refactoring like "Check string parameter for not null or white space" that will be suggested on string parameters only?

```
public void Method(string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is possible using context action. I don't know with what exact version this was introduced, but at least with 2016.1 it should be there.

[image]

Besides that, you can use [live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html) for some needs. They have some limitations though. If you reach them, you can create a custom plugin that implements a [context action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk/README.html) for instance.